# Gerar pacote para publicação na Apple Store

Tags: ios, apache-cordova

Eu criei um app em **PhoneGap** e preciso agora gerar um pacote para publicar na loja da **Apple**, minha dúvida é a seguinte: existe uma forma de criar esse pacote sem ter um *Mac* e o *Xcode*? Eu tenho conta de desenvolvedor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para desenvolver e testar seu aplicativo em **PhoneGap** de fato não é necessário um *Mac*. Todo esse processo você consegue encontrar na própria internet em vários artigos. Pela sua dúvida, acredito que esta etapa você já alcançou.

Agora, para submeter seu aplicativo você realmente vai precisar de um Mac após ter em mãos seu pacote **.ipa** através do [Adobe PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/), por exemplo.

No *Mac* o processo é bem simples e rápido. Pelo **Application Loader** tudo que você vai fazer é entrar com seus dados de desenvolvedor, selecionar o pacote gerado e então realizar o upload. Infelizmente não tem outra maneira, 99% do processo pode ser feito em um *PC*, mas o envio para publicação deve ser no *Mac*.

Comment: Paulo eu consegui um mac e enviei pelo XCODE, recebi um e-mail dizendo que foi enviado ... etc mas já tem uma semana e não recebi mais nenhum reporte deles e nem consigo ver nada no itunes connect, sabe me dizer se tem alguma forma de acompanhar o status ?

Comment: Thiago, [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html) tem as definições dos status disponíveis. Normalmente o que mais demora é o *Waiting For Review*, pode durar mais de 1 semana, após isso ele entra em revisão e se não for rejeitado ficará como *Ready for Sale* em verde. No *iTunnes Connect* você consegue acompanhar isso pelo histórico, fica lá no fim da página.

Comment: Opa perfeito muito obrigado!!